# Dynamics CRM - Get Name of Relationship

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, relationship

Is there any way to get the name of a relationship given the from and to entities?

I have a fairly dynamic piece of code that needs to `Associate` or `Disassociate` entities. In order to call these functions, I need to know the name of the relationship. I am not sure how to determine the relationship name just given the two entities.

For example, my code might need to disassociate an account with a contact. How can I determine the relationship name of "account_primary_contact"?

Comment: What version of CRM are you running?

Comment: You'll have to use metadata service calls to retrieve the relationships supported by one of the entities, then filter out those relationships where the related entity isn't the other one. I can write up a more detailed answer tomorrow, but in the meantime, have you considered that a given pair of entities might have more than one relationship? Given only the two entities, and more than one relationship between them, you don't have enough information to decide which relationship you want to target - unless the idea is to associate/disassociate using *all* possible relationships.

Comment: After giving this some thought I think that what you are trying to do is fundamentally flawed.  It doesn't make sense to disassociate entities without knowing what relationship you are dissociating.  Perhaps more information about the context you are working in can lead us to a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of answering the question despite my not understanding why you would want to do this:

```cs
foreach (OneToManyRelationshipMetadata relationshipMetaData in primaryEntityMetadata.ManyToOneRelationships)
{
    if (relationshipMetaData.ReferencingEntity == relatedEntity.LogicalName)
    {
        string relationshipName = relationshipMetaData.SchemaName;
        //Do something with your relationship?
    }
}
```

Where primaryEntityMetadata is of type EntityMetadata and ReferencingEntity is of type Entity.  Then use similar logic for checking Many to One relationships.

Comment: In my situation, I knew the two entities I wanted to disassociated with one another. For instance, removing the primary contact from an account. I know the "account" name and it's ID and I know the primary contact's name and it ID. I just didn't know how to determine the relationship name of "account_primary_contact". With this, I can look for the account relationship name where primary contact is the related entity. I then just build my entity collection and call `Associate` \ `Disassociate`. This is only necessary because my form is so dynamic in nature.

Comment: @TravisParks If you don't know the name of the relationship at compile time, how do you know you've found the right relationship at runtime? As I mentioned in my other comment, nothing prevents there being more than one relationship between the same two entities. And if you know for a fact that this isn't the case, then why don't you know the name of the relationship at compile time?

Comment: @shambulator Thank you for repeating your question. The second time around I finally saw your point. In our system we have `modifiedby`, `createdby`, `ownerid`, etc. that link an account to a user. Just knowing the two sides isn't enough. Fortunately, our CRM admins had the clairvoyance to come up with a naming convention. It is always follows the `left_right_attribute` naming convention. Had you not repeated yourself, I might have wiped out other relationships accidentally. Phew!